# How to remove the default editor inserted in a custom module

Tags: module, custom-field

I have created a custom module in Joomla 3.5; I have a set of fields, but surprisingly, a default editor is inserted into the module `basic` tab, while I have not such fields in my fields XML:

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">

                <field name="title" label="Title" type="text" />
                <field name="subtitle" label="Subtitle" type="text" />
                <field name="title-class" label="Title CSS Class" type="text" />
                <field name="subtitle-class" label="Subtitle CSS Class" type="text" />
</fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
```

Does anyone know what's the issue and how can I remove this textarea?

Comment: So one of those 4 fields has the default editor? I would start by commenting out parts of the xml file. Take off all fields and see how it looks, then start re-inserting the fields in the xml, one by one...

Comment: I've created a module and copied your code into the config section - the problem is not replicated for me.  Are the other fields appearing alongside the editor?  What label is the editor given?  It may be worth expanding your question to show the full xml file and a screengrab of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if your custom module XML file contains the following line:

```
<customContent />
```

This line is present in the default Joomla Custom HTML module, and inserts an editor field in the main tab of your module, even when it's not located inside the `<config>` tag.

Comment: Hey man this was the solution. Thanks very much

Comment: great catch johanpw